# Is it possible to get other user's current location if it's not stored in database?

Tags: android, geolocation

I have successfully implemented Google Places Search in my app where I can search for locations, which were stored in my database from my current location.

However, I was wondering if it's possible to search *other* users' current location that are using my app (provided they consent to this function) where their data is not stored in my database. Is there any tutorials out there that I missed out because I've searched high and low for this but it only returned the Google Places tutorial.

I want something like if I go to a certain place, then my app will tell me that there are other users currently hanging out say 5 km from my current location. Maybe something like FindMyFriends app or something.

This is for android based app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to know where another phone is, unless they tell each other.  The easiest way to do this is through a central database.  Other ways exist, but are either so short range as to not be useful, or would require them to directly connect to each other over the internet, which is problematic (usually blocked by NATs, ips change as they switch from 1 wifi network to another or from wifi to cellular).  The reason people usually use a db and central server is that it makes things much easier.

Comment: If the app allows the user to check in their location, in which their location will then be stored in a database, then I reckon that's a possibility?

Comment: Yes, that's the standard way of doing it. Send the location to a server which stores it and later sends it to other users

Comment: Thanks! Sorry it's such a noob question. I'm a newbie in the android world & in programming as well.